# Tailwind CSS - sm:text-2xl overriding w-4xl

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, node.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to make my Pages responsive and change text size when the screen size is small ,
i am doing everything properly and the order is also correct. But when i set sm , it overrides everything else , irrespective of the property i am trying to change

```
import React from "react";

export const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col w-screen justify-evenly items-center mt-16">
      <div
        id="details-main-1"
        className="flex flex-col items-center justify-evenly text-slate-900 text-6xl"
      >
        Welcome to the <span className="text-slate-300"> Home Page</span>
      </div>
      <div id="details-main-2 text-black text-xl " className="text-4xl sm:text-2xl">
        hello
      </div>
      <div id="details-main-3"></div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind breakpoint work on min-width then you need to explicit from higher to minimum.

This is the table

| Breakpoint | prefix | Minimum width CSS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sm | 640px | `@media (min-width: 640px) { ... }` |
| md | 768px | `@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }` |
| lg | 1024px | `@media (min-width: 1024px) { ... }` |
| xl | 1280px | `@media (min-width: 1280px) { ... }` |
| 2xl | 1536px | `@media (min-width: 1536px) { ... }` |

Then when you write this `text-4xl sm:text-2xl` you said:

When width is over 640px then text is 2XL.

I think you want this:

`text-2xl sm:text-4xl`